# NSInvalidArgumentException -[NSNull length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, crash-reports, crashlytics

I have following crash report and unable where it caused crash. Because I used Length field anywhere.
Do you have any idea about cause of this crash:

```
Thread : Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x0000000182b78f5c __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x000000019776bf80 objc_exception_throw
2  CoreFoundation                 0x0000000182b7fc6c __methodDescriptionForSelector
3  CoreFoundation                 0x0000000182b7cc14 ___forwarding___
4  CoreFoundation                 0x0000000182a80dcc _CF_forwarding_prep_0
5  UIKit                          0x00000001880da13c -[UILabel _textRectForBounds:limitedToNumberOfLines:includingShadow:]
6  UIKit                          0x00000001880da030 -[UILabel _intrinsicSizeWithinSize:]
7  UIKit                          0x00000001881d5328 -[UILabel intrinsicContentSize]
8  UIKit                          0x00000001881d5188 -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _generateContentSizeConstraints]
9  UIKit                          0x00000001881d4b9c -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _updateContentSizeConstraints]
10 UIKit                          0x00000001881d0c3c -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) updateConstraints]
11 UIKit                          0x00000001881d4940 -[UILabel updateConstraints]
12 UIKit                          0x00000001888f9e8c -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _internalUpdateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPassAndViewsNeedingBaselineUpdate:forSecondPass:]
13 UIKit                          0x00000001888fa0f4 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPassAndViewsNeedingBaselineUpdate:forSecondPass:]
14 UIKit                          0x00000001888f9dbc -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _internalUpdateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPassAndViewsNeedingBaselineUpdate:forSecondPass:]
15 UIKit                          0x00000001888fa0f4 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPassAndViewsNeedingBaselineUpdate:forSecondPass:]
16 UIKit                          0x00000001888f9dbc -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _internalUpdateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPassAndViewsNeedingBaselineUpdate:forSecondPass:]
17 UIKit                          0x00000001888fa0f4 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPassAndViewsNeedingBaselineUpdate:forSecondPass:]
18 UIKit                          0x00000001888f9dbc -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _internalUpdateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPassAndViewsNeedingBaselineUpdate:forSecondPass:]
19 Foundation                     0x0000000183a14aa0 -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:]
20 UIKit                          0x00000001881d3958 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _withAutomaticEngineOptimizationDisabledIfEngineExists:]
21 UIKit                          0x00000001888fa0c8 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPassAndViewsNeedingBaselineUpdate:forSecondPass:]
22 UIKit                          0x00000001888f9dbc -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _internalUpdateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPassAndViewsNeedingBaselineUpdate:forSecondPass:]
23 UIKit                          0x00000001888fa0f4 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPassAndViewsNeedingBaselineUpdate:forSecondPass:]
24 UIKit                          0x00000001888f9dbc -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _internalUpdateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPassAndViewsNeedingBaselineUpdate:forSecondPass:]
25 UIKit                          0x00000001888fa0f4 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPassAndViewsNeedingBaselineUpdate:forSecondPass:]
26 UIKit                          0x00000001888f9dbc -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _internalUpdateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPassAndViewsNeedingBaselineUpdate:forSecondPass:]
27 UIKit                          0x00000001888fa0f4 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPassAndViewsNeedingBaselineUpdate:forSecondPass:]
28 UIKit                          0x00000001881d483c __60-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) updateConstraintsIfNeeded]_block_invoke
29 UIKit                          0x00000001881d3968 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _withAutomaticEngineOptimizationDisabledIfEngineExists:]
30 UIKit                          0x00000001881d4470 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) updateConstraintsIfNeeded]
31 UIKit                          0x00000001888fa798 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsAtEngineLevelIfNeeded]
32 UIKit                          0x00000001883d1fcc -[UIView(Hierarchy) _updateConstraintsAsNecessaryAndApplyLayoutFromEngine]
33 UIKit                          0x00000001880cb038 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:]
34 QuartzCore                     0x00000001878d1f14 -[CALayer layoutSublayers]
35 QuartzCore                     0x00000001878ccb20 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*)
36 QuartzCore                     0x00000001878cc9e0 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*)
37 QuartzCore                     0x00000001878cc07c CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*)
38 QuartzCore                     0x00000001878cbdd0 CA::Transaction::commit()
39 UIKit                          0x00000001880ce0dc _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue
40 CoreFoundation                 0x0000000182b305a4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__
41 CoreFoundation                 0x0000000182b30038 __CFRunLoopDoSources0
42 CoreFoundation                 0x0000000182b2dd38 __CFRunLoopRun
43 CoreFoundation                 0x0000000182a5cdc0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
44 GraphicsServices               0x000000018dbb0088 GSEventRunModal
45 UIKit                          0x0000000188136f60 UIApplicationMain
46 Olgera                         0x000000010016c938 main (main.m:15)
47 libdyld.dylib                  0x0000000197f968b8 start
```

Also I have question if length property of UILabel caused this or maybe NSNull object was another type object?

Comment: It seems like you're asking for the length of an object that i null, but without any code it's hard to say exactly. You can try asking the object if it's null before you asking for it's length, like this: [object isKindOfClass [NSNull class]]

Comment: @turingtested Yes I think so I should add this comparison before use of length. I've used length about 70 times :). Thanks anyway

Comment: Add breakpoints and log messages to locate the crash. It's my best tip.

Comment: Is it possible to get NSNull outside of my project? I fixed problem of AFNetworking but there is still NSNull.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[NSNull null]` is a special singleton value used to represent `null` values in collection types that don't allow `nil` such as `NSArray` and `NSDictionary`.

If you know that a certain value, coming from a server for example, can be `null` you need to check for that before attempting to treat it as some other value

```
NSDictionary *data = ...
NSString *name = [data objectForKey:@"name"];
// This will cause a crash if the value of the
// `name` key was `null` since objectForKey:
// will return [NSNull null] 
if ([name length] > 0) { 
 // Do something
}
```

What you want to do is check that the value is not `null` before using it in any way

```
if (name != [NSNull null]) {
  if ([name length] > 0) {
    // Do something
  }
}
```

Comment: I was getting NSNull from AFNetworking and it caused my problem. The root problem was server side which as you said, sent null as response.
So I used `[serializer setRemovesKeysWithNullValues:YES]` and now null value will be nil not NSNull. Thanks